# Call coffeescript function from jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, coffeescript

I have two files: first one is a plain jQuery, and a second one is a Coffeescript

jQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkPrice();
});
```

CoffeeScript file:

```
$ ->
   checkPrice = ->
     alert("OK");
```

I get following error: "Unhandled Error: Undefined variable: checkPrice"

In the template they are included in opposite direction: coffeescript file, then jquery file.

Is there some way to make them working together ?

Answer (score 1):

OK. Got it.

checkPrice should have been declared as global, so in coffeescript file I have:

```
window.checkPrice =->
  alert("OK");
```

And now it works!

Thank's everyone who was there to help me anyway.