# Initiate confetti effect (canvas) with JQuery

Tags: jquery, canvas

I'd like to initiate this confetti effect when the user clicks with Jquery, but I'm not sure how, is there an easy way I could do this from an external js file with JQuery?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpzxL

N

```
UM_CONFETTI = 350
COLORS = [[85,71,106], [174,61,99], [219,56,83], [244,92,68], [248,182,70]]
PI_2 = 2*Math.PI


canvas = document.getElementById "world"
context = canvas.getContext "2d"
window.w = 0
window.h = 0

resizeWindow = ->
  window.w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth
  window.h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight
```

.....

That's just a snippet of the code it's all in that codepen example.

Comment: Not a good solution, but you could hide the canvis until they do something with jQuery.  Also, couldn't you have the jQuery action call the step()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604175/call-coffeescript-function-from-jquery-function

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event to the `step()` function which actually draws the animation.

```
window.step = ->
    requestAnimationFrame(step)
    context.clearRect(0,0,w,h)
    c.draw() for c in confetti

$('#button').click(step) ->
```